# How do I catch rejections from multiple functions?

Tags: javascript

I am refactoring some code and removing unnecessary callbacks.

The original code was:

```
create(_job_id).then(function (create_id) {
    latest().then(function (latest_config) {
        update(create_id).then(function () {    

            // More code

        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);                       
        });
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);                       
    });
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);                       
});
```

I have refactored it to:

```
const setup = async () => {

    const create_id  = create(_job_id);
    const latest_config = await latest();
    await update(create_id);
    return { create_id, latest_config };
}

setup().then((setup) => {
    console.log(setup);
})
```

But now the rejections are not handled. How would I go about elegantly handling the "catches". `Promises.all` looks good but I have tried to use it unsuccessfully.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you add `.catch(err => {//do sth with err})` on the `setup()` as you do the `then()` ?

Comment: What about wrapping each of the async awaits with try catch blocks? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: Great, thanks @AliBeyit Add as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Avoid lots of `catch(function (err) { console.log(err); });`  Your errors should propagate to a central error handler,.. What's even worse  here is that you don't re-throw the errors so would likely leave your application in a very unstable state.

Comment: Shouldn't `const create_id  = create(_job_id);` be `const create_id  = await create(_job_id);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `.catch(err => {//do sth with err})` on the `setup()` as you do the `then()`. Which means it catches any of the exception returned by `setup()`.

```
setup()
.then((setup) => {
    console.log(setup);
})
.catch(err => {console.log("Error", err.message)})
```

Comment: I'd personally remove the curly braces from the arrow functions if the code is only one line. `setup().then(setup => console.log(setup)).catch(err => console.log(err));` If you need to break it down over multiple lines I'd split before the line before  the `.` in `.then` or `.catch`.

Answer (score 2):

The non-`async` version could also look like this:

```
const p_latest_config = latest();

create(_job_id)
  .then(create_id => {
    update(create_id).catch(err => console.log(err));
    return Promise.all([create_id, p_latest_config]);
  })
  .then(([create_id, latest_config]) => ({create_id, latest_config}))
  .then(setup => console.log(setup))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The above assumes that `create(_job_id)`, `latest()` and `update(create_id)` are not depended on each other via internal mutation.